# ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD leaves empty white space at top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using sherlock action bar in my app and in a few fragments I want the tabs gone.
By now I'm using ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD and it does disappear the tabs but there's an empty white line left at the top of the screen:

[image]

I've searched for similiar cases and haven't found exactly the same case.
I'm not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748199/make-actionbar-overlay-using-actionbarsherlock) is similiar to mine but I still couldnt figure how to remove that white space.

Here's the actionbar code:

```
final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        Tab tab1 = bar.newTab()
                  .setText("1")
                  .setTabListener(new TabListener<one>(this, "tab1", one.class));
        bar.addTab(tab1);
        Tab tab2 = bar.newTab()
                .setText("2")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<two>(this, "tab2", two.class));
         bar.addTab(tab2);
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the Tabs bar and add tabs anyway to your ActionBar ?

Comment: I want that the tab navigation will be availabe in specific fragments and not evreywhere.

Comment: Okay, so you have to hide manually the ActionBar if you want some fullscreen display. But be careful with that, it can be weird for the user to see tabs disappear.

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I'll pay attention for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "empty space" is the ActionBar no ?

What about the ActionBar.hide() method ?